# SQL Server Create Function With Variable Column For Aggregation / Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

Suppose I have the following 2 tables in my SQL Server (2008) DB:

**Table1:**

```
Col1:    ...   Map:
1        ...   a
2        ...   a
3        ...   b
4        ...   c
5        ...   c
```

**Mapper:**

```
Map:     Out1:    Out2: ...
a        ab       ac
b        ab       bd
c        cd       ac
d        cd       bd   
    ... (whatever) ...
```

Now, I would like to create a table valued function that would return something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT 
   M.Out1, 
   SUM(T.Col1)
FROM
   Table1 as T,
   Mapper as M
WHERE
   T.Map = M.Map
GROUP BY
   M.Out1
```

**HOWEVER** I would like to be able to include a parameter which can dictate which column of `Mapper` to Return / Group By (ie, Not be limited to `Out1`, but also be able to return the query grouped by possibly `Map` or `Out2`, etc based upon some form of user input (I would assume typing in the col. name as the defining input)).

I've seen posts that say you can do this using dynamic SQL, but warn of SQL Injection... Is there a better way??

Thanks!!

Comment: If you use QUOTENAME in your dyanmic sql you should be ok. Just wrap your column name (the variable) with QUOTENAME.

Comment: Awesome, @SeanLange, never heard of that! - Going to look into that now!! - Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example loosely based on your example. Notice I also changed your join to the ANSI-92 style join instead of the older ANSI-89 style join. This is easier to read and less prone to accidental cross joins.

```
declare @ColumnNameParameter sysname = 'MyColumn;] that is injection safe'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = 
'select M.' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnNameParameter) 
+ ', SUM(T.Col1)
from Table1 as T
join Mapper as M on M.Map = t.Map
GROUP BY M.' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnNameParameter) 

select @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that I can tell:

1) Use `sp_executesql` and store the results into a temp table that is also dynamically created. In this instance you should be able to run a `'SELECT [custom column mapping columns] INTO #TEMPTable FROM [Mapped/Joined Table[s]]`'

2) Use CLR from within SQL.

Sorry, I noticed I didn't respond to your concern about SQL Injection. It's always something to be aware of and if you're worried about it then you can parse the user-input before adding it into the statement. For instance, you can make sure there is only one word present, doesn't extend past a particular length, doesn't contain any SQL keywords such as SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc.

Comment: Those types of validation are not even close to good enough to prevent sql injection. Injection attacks do not have to be in clear text.

Comment: If it's not in clear-text then I'd assume it would be an attack to inject executable code by attempting to cause a buffer-overflow. In such a case, checking the length of the returned user-input should suffice, should it not?

Comment: Not if you are directly executing it. I have a meeting in about 10 minutes but will find you an example of this when I get back.

Comment: The challenge is sql injection using binary. Do a google search for sql injection binary and you can see how this can work.